# XSLT following Sibling issue

Tags: xslt-1.0

```
<root>
        <A>
            ...
        </A>
        <A1>Text</A1>
        <A1>Text</A1>
        <B1>Text</B1>
        <C1>Text</C1>
        <A>
           ..
        </A>
        <A1>Text</A1>
```

In the above example I want to select all the siblings of first A which are A1.If I put "following-sibling::*[self::A]" then it will select only the first A1. But I want to select all A1 which are followed by A. There is no rule like B1 tag will come after A1. Any tag can come after A1.
Please help to sort this issue.

Comment: If your question is about XSLT, edit your question and show a [minimal, complete and verifiable sample of your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For XSLT questions this means: a sample of your XML input, a full stylesheet and the output you expect.

Answer (score 0):

> If I put "following-sibling::*[self::A]" then it will select only the
>   first A1.

I think you meant:

```
following-sibling::*[self::A1]
```

which can be written simply as:

```
following-sibling::A1
```

This **will** select **all** `A1` nodes that are following siblings of the context node. You may *think* it only selects the first one because of how you use the `select` statement. For example, in XSLT 1.0 the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::A1"/>
```

will return the value of the first `A1` node in the selected set.